# TextMate Grammar - Problem with `end` expression

Tags: textmate

I'm having huge problems with the `end` portion of a regex in TextMate:

1. It looks like `end` becomes the part of the pattern that's returned between `begin` and `end`
2. Trying to apply multiple endings with one negative lookbehind proves unsuccessful

Here is an example code:

```
property_name: {
    test1: [1, 50, 5000]
    test2: something ;;
    test3: [
        1, 
        50, 
        5000
    ]
    test4: "string"
    test5: [
        "text",
        "text2"
    ]
    test6: something2
    test7: something3
}
```

I'm using the following code:

```
"begin": "\\b([a-z_]+):",
"beginCaptures": {
    "1": {
        "name" : "parameter.name"
    }
}
"end": "(?<!,)\\n(?!\\])",
"patterns": [
    {
        "name": "parameter.value",
        "match": "(.+)"
    }
]
```

My logic for the `end` regular expression is to consider it ended if there's a new line but only if it's not preceded by a comma (list of values in an array) or followed by a closing square bracket (last value in an array).

Unfortunately it's not working as expected.

What I would like to achieve is that all `property_name#` and `test` are matched as **parameter.name** and the values are matched as **parameter.value** apart from `;;`

Comment: Patterns in TextMate are always applied per line, so putting a `\n` in an `end` pattern doesn't make sense. From [a great blog](https://www.apeth.com/nonblog/stories/textmatebundle.html) about developing TextMate grammars: "The TextMate parser will not examine more than one line of text at a time; thus, a regular expression that includes a newline (\n) anywhere other than as the last matched character will never match."